# populate primefaces autocomplete with dropdown

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**In JSF using primeface**

```
<p:autoComplete minQueryLength="5" value="#{itemManagementMB.itemManagementLazy.code}" forceSelection="true" autocomplete="false"
    completeMethod="#{itemManagementMB.autoCompleteUsindCode}" dropdown="true">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{itemManagementMB.handleSelect}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

When I enter **5 keywords** that working fine. but I want implement in that way , if user enter **4 words** and press dropdown it populate autocomplete based on 4 keywords.

One thing is blocking me that when I click on dropdown, `autoCompleteUsindCode(String query)` method take empty string and `itemManagementMB.itemManagementLazy.code` also empty.

any **update** ? / **solution**?

Comment: can you post also the content of your autoCompleteUsindCode() method?

Comment: From what I can see in your code the forceSelection="true" attribute is what's causing your autoCompleteUsindCode method get an empty string. why not just make minQueryLength to 4 and let the completeMethod trigger on its own?

Comment: @Fritz I remove `forceSelection="true"` attribute. same behavior. `why not just make minQueryLength to 4 and let the completeMethod trigger on its own?` This is client requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a lot, I solved in that way

**Solution:**

```
<p:autoComplete id="anum" minQueryLength="5" value="#{transferInMB.itemManagementLazy.code}" forceSelection="true"
    completeMethod="#{transferInMB.autoCompleteUsingCode}" dropdown="true">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{transferInMB.handleSelect}" />
    <p:ajax event="keyup" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

I just add the following

```
<p:ajax event="keyup" />
```

Comment: so what basically happened after you placed the keyup ajax event? where you able to get the 4 keywords in your backing bean?

Comment: @Fritz `value="#{transferInMB.itemManagementLazy.code}"`

Answer (score 1):

As per Primefaces 5.1 User Guide page 29, I quote:

> **Dropdown Mode**
>
> When *dropdown mode* is enabled, a dropdown button is displayed next to
>   the input field, clicking this button will do a search with an empty
>   query, a regular completeMethod implementation should load all
>   available items as a response.